# Split a directory based on the filename prefix

Tags: linux, file-management

I have a very large directory with probably millions of small files in it. It's taking forever to run ls on the directory.

Is there an easy script that I can run to split the directory into smaller ones, based on the prefixes of the filenames. My goal is to wind up with something similar to what the [Debian archives' pool directory](http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/pool/main/) looks like.

Comment: What do you know about the prefixes? It's hard to whack together a solution if you don't know any, unless you want to sort them by first letter, or brute force search through the filenames for common prefixes.

Comment: First letter (or first two) is fine for me. I don't need special lib directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this too simple? Just push every file into a single letter directory based on the file first character.

```
#!/bin/sh


for i in `/bin/ls | xargs`
do
    dir=`echo $i | cut -c 1 -`
    mkdir -p $dir
    mv $i $dir
done
```

You don't get the 'lib' directories, but you could make special rules for other prefixes.

Comment: [Don't loop over `ls` output.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) The fix is also much simpler than the buggy version; `for i in * `

Comment: ... also, the pipe to `xargs` does absolutely nothing useful here, though it's merely useless, not actually harmful.